# Position fixed like element in absolute element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a UI where whenever I hover on an element, the element specific description will be visible just adjacent to it. I somehow managed to make it work properly but now I came to know that when the elements are more then there should be scroller.

Doing the following, I get the scroller but now the description section is not moving with the scroller.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t8wtxf4o/)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    height: 180px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
.viewer {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
.item:hover {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.item:hover .viewer {
    display: block;
}
```

I am looking for a pure solution which works in modern browsers like IE10, chrome and firefox.

Comment: Basically, you need to check which area is in viewport and then update that accordingly. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: @odedta if you are suggesting me a javascript solution then FYi, I can do it by calculating the scrollTop but here I am looking for css solution. Just for learning.

Comment: Somethings like that? http://jsfiddle.net/t8wtxf4o/1/

Comment: @odedta not even close :). I actually solved everything in the provided fiddle above. it is just that when I scroll the container, the description section is not showing adjacent to the hovered element.

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/t8wtxf4o/2/

Comment: @odedta no....  the description section should stretch its height to the container.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t8wtxf4o/3/ ? :P

Comment: @odedta scroll and check.. the description section is not visible. are you trolling me?

Comment: No, I honestly don't understand exactly what it is you want.

Comment: @odedta no problem. I got the solution below. check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to ensure that the `viewer` div doesn't scroll with the rest of the items. To do this, you can add a second wrapper. The outer wrapper **does not** scroll, and the inner wrapper **does** scroll. Then, you need to make sure your absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the **outer/non-scrolling** wrapper. You can do this by removing the positioning from the inner wrapper, and instead applying it to the outer wrapper.

For example:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
.wrapper-inner {
    height: 180px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The jsFiddle can be viewed here: https://jsfiddle.net/t8wtxf4o/4/

Comment: Awesome, I was so close to this but somehow I was adding `position: relative` to the `wrapper-inner`.

Comment: @Mr_Green always happens! Glad to know this is working for you.